# I would like to put one single icon in the Desktop that actually opens the Desktop. Any ideas?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, desktop, desktop-environment, productivity

The idea is to turn my Desktop into a place where I can put a image reference of what I am learning at the moment. This would be an [example](http://michael.peopleofhonoronly.com/vim/vim_cheat_sheet_for_programmers_screen.png)

This means:

- puttig an image of the reference of what I'm learning as a background of the Desktop (already possible)
- having the icons of files, folders or even removable USB pens available (one click away) but without blocking te view to that background

Any Ideas? Or alternative solutions?

Comment: You mean you want the image as a background?

Comment: Would you rephrase your question. It's very confusing.

Comment: @terdon Exactly. But without the icons blocking the view to that background.

Comment: Why don't you just create a folder on the desktop and move all your desktop icons into that folder?

Comment: @slybloty Done. Is this more clear?

Comment: @terdon Because there are virtual icons that I want to keep. And some of them are created gnome in response to certain events. An example is plugged in USB pens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer to my question but, until now, it IS the best solution I could find.

I wrote a script called `cs` with the following code

```
    #!/bin/sh
    eog --fullscreen [path to the image I want to see]
```

and placed it in `~/bin` since this is in my `$PATH`.

Then I run:

```
    chmod +x ~/bin/cs
```

Finally, to get access to it, I just press `Alt-F2` and then `cs`  (as in cheatsheet) followed by `Enter`.

This if far from ideal since I:

- can't click on it
- don't have a single keyboard command defined for it
- have to remember it is there instead of having it by default

So, if you have a better solution, please state it.